# SWI-Prolog ODBC interface - number of cursors

Tags: prolog, odbc, swi-prolog

I'm using the [SWI-Prolog ODBC interface](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section(%27packages/odbc.html%27)) to connect with an Oracle Xe 12.0 database. Upon repeated usage of the system I get the ORA-01000 error, "maximum number of open cursors exceeded"; which then forces me to restart the application.

There's a plethora of questions on StackOverflow about this error, but none of them relating to the SWI-Prolog ODBC interface. I investigated and tested with the code (sampled below) and discovered that calling `odbc_prepare/4` and then `odbc_execute/3` does *not* free the ODBC statement object.

Here's the test I ran. After connecting (with the appropriate DSN, user and password):

```
:- odbc_connect(DSN,C,[user(USER),password(PASSWD),alias(swi),open(once)]).
```

My test predicate, where 'a_table' is a table in the database with a column 'colname':

```
go_test(N):-
   N1 is N+1,
   write(N1),nl,
   odbc_prepare(swi,'select count(colname) from a_table',[],Statement),
   odbc_execute(Statement,[]),
   %(point of change)
   go_test(N1).
```

Prints up to 300 then crashes with the error (which is what I expect, as running a `select value from v$parameter where name = ‘open_cursors’;` in SQL Plus tells me 300).

By replacing "*%(point of change)*" with `odbc_free_statement(Statement),`, `go_test` seems to run indefinitely.

However, although (I *think*) I have paired each `odbc_prepare` and `odbc_execute` with a `odbc_free_statement` in my program; I **still** get the error after (a lot more) usage. Is there anything else that might be causing this "cursor leak"?

I'm aware that there are queries I could run in SQL Plus to try and identify the increase in usage of connection cursors, but it seems hard to coordinate that with predicate calls in a Prolog application. What would really help me would be a way of querying, through SWI-Prolog's ODBC interface, the number of cursors a current connection is using. Ideally, something like `odbc_get_connection` could do it; but none of the [properties](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=odbc_get_connection/2) are what I'm looking for. How can I find out, through the SWI-Prolog ODBC interface, the number of active connection cursors?